# getParcelableArrayListExtra return nullpointerexception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, parcelable

I have a problem with getParcelableArrayListExtra and Null Pointer Exception.

**Working**

My Activity:

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    fetch = new ArrayList<Custom>();
    generateEntries();

    Log.i("fetch", fetch.toString());

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CustomObject.class);
    //myIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("my", fetch);
    myIntent.putExtra("my", "name");
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

CustomObject:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customobject);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    recievedList = new ArrayList<Custom>();

    in = getIntent();

    String s = bu.getString("my");

    Log.i("s", "s");
}
```

**NOT working**

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    fetch = new ArrayList<Custom>();
    generateEntries();

    Log.i("fetch", fetch.toString());

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CustomObject.class);
    myIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("my", fetch);
    //myIntent.putExtra("my", "name");
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

CustomObject:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customobject);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    recievedList = new ArrayList<Custom>();

    in = getIntent();

    recievedList = in.getParcelableArrayListExtra("my"); // NULL POINTER EXCEPTION
}
```

What is the problem with ArrayList?

Anybody help me?

.....................................................................................................

```
public class Custom implements Parcelable {

    private String alarmTitle;
    private String alarmType;
    private String alarmTime;
    private String alarmDate;
    private List<String> shortVakatName;
    private List<String> vakatActive;

    public Custom(String entry1, List<String> list1, List<String> list2, String entry3, String entry4, String entry5){

        this.shortVakatName = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.vakatActive = new ArrayList<String>();

        this.alarmTitle = entry1;
        this.shortVakatName = list1;
        this.vakatActive = list2;
        this.alarmType = entry3;
        this.alarmTime = entry4;
        this.alarmDate = entry5;
    }

    private Custom(Parcel in){
        alarmTitle = in.readString();
        in.readStringList(shortVakatName);
        in.readStringList(vakatActive);
        alarmTime = in.readString();
        alarmDate = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Custom> CREATOR =
            new Parcelable.Creator<Custom>() {

        public Custom createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Custom(source);
        }

        public Custom[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Custom[size];
        }

    };

    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(alarmTitle);
        dest.writeStringList(shortVakatName);
        dest.writeStringList(vakatActive);
        dest.writeString(alarmType);
        dest.writeString(alarmTime);
        dest.writeString(alarmDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: in your code, you're doing a `in.getString("my")` instead of `in.getParcelableArrayListExtra("my")`

Comment: could you give us Parcelable methods of your class Custom ? Do you have implemented Parcelable.Creator ( newArray & createFromParcel ) like in the doc : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: You should post the code for the `Custom` class, particularly the parceling bits.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem comes when you are unpacking the parcel to create a new object.  Specifically, your calls to `readStringList()`.  This method is designed to fill an existing object with data from the parcel, not to create a new one.

Realize that when the parcel is unpacked, the constructor that takes a `Parcel` as a parameter is being called, per the definition of your `Parcelable.CREATOR`, and NOT the other parameterized constructor.  Therefore, neither `shortVakatName` nor `vakatActive` were ever initialized to anything (they are null pointers).

You can fix the issue by doing one of two things, either let the Parcel create the `List` for you when inflating the data:

```
private Custom(Parcel in){
    alarmTitle = in.readString();
    shortVakatName = in.createStringArrayList();
    vakatActive = in.createStringArrayList();
    alarmType = in.readString();
    alarmTime = in.readString();
    alarmDate = in.readString();
}
```

Or, create the objects before telling `Parcel` to fill it with data.

```
private Custom(Parcel in){
    shortVakatName = new ArrayList<String>();
    vakatActive = new ArrayList<String>();

    alarmTitle = in.readString();
    in.readStringList(shortVakatName);
    in.readStringList(vakatActive);
    alarmType = in.readString();
    alarmTime = in.readString();
    alarmDate = in.readString();
}
```

Also notice, in both examples, I fixed the reading order to match your `writeToParcel()` method (you were missing the `alarmType` parameter, which would have led to strange results when you passed your data through the `Intent`.

HTH

Comment: I wish i could vote this up more than once, I've been stuck with this for a couple of days and I almost gave up using parcels, Thanks for explaining the concept rather than just writing a working code.

Comment: thnx.. this has helped me