# Unparcel Error Android

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, parcelable, parcel

I am running into an issue where instantiating an `Object` from a `Parcel` is throwing a `NullPointerException`. My Class *Contact* implements `Parcelable`, contains a CREATOR, and all the hookups seem to work. A *Contact* object represents a contact in an Address book. The variables used are of types:

```
String firstName, lastName, note;
List<String> emails, phones;
```

The constructor initializes all the strings to "" and all the lists to empty lists. The `writeToParcel` and `Contact(Parcel in)` methods are shown below:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(firstName);
    out.writeString(lastName);

    //If there are emails, write a 1 followed by the list. Otherwise, write a 0
    if (!emails.isEmpty())
    {
        out.writeInt(1);
        out.writeStringList(emails);
    }
    else
        out.writeInt(0);

    //If there are phone numbers, write a 1 followed by the list. Otherwise, write a 0
    if (!phones.isEmpty())
    {
        out.writeInt(1);
        out.writeStringList(phones);
    }
    else
        out.writeInt(0);
    out.writeString(note);
}
```

...

```
public Contact(Parcel in)
{
    firstName = in.readString();
    Log.i(TAG, firstName);
    lastName = in.readString();
    Log.i(TAG, lastName);
    int emailsExist = in.readInt();
    if (emailsExist == 1)
        in.readStringList(emails);
    else
        emails = new ArrayList<String>();
    int phonesExist = in.readInt();
    if (phonesExist == 1)
        in.readStringList(phones);//Line 80, where this app breaks
    else
        phones = new ArrayList<String>();
    note = in.readString();
}
```

The test I am currently working on provides a valid first and last name, one phone number, and a note. The relevant output I get when upacking this parcelable is as follows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo...
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.Parcel.readStringList(Parcel.java:1718)
    at com.mycompany.android.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:80) //This is the line marked above
    at com.mycompany.android.Contact$1.createFromParcel(Contact.java:40) //This is inside the CREATOR
    ...
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Can numbers not be written as String lists, or did I do something incorrectly?

Comment: According to [getParcelableArrayListExtra return nullpointerexception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902380/getparcelablearraylistextra-return-nullpointerexception), you can simply write the empty `List<String>` arrays in `writeToParcel()` and use [`Parcel#createStringArrayList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createStringArrayList%28%29) to read them later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just poked around a few minutes more, and realized my mistake. The `readStringList` method cannot receive a *null* argument. My new `Contact(Parcel in)` method is as follows:

```
public Contact(Parcel in)
{
    firstName = in.readString();
    Log.i(TAG, firstName);
    lastName = in.readString();
    Log.i(TAG, lastName);
    int emailsExist = in.readInt();
    emails = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (emailsExist == 1)
        in.readStringList(emails);
    int phonesExist = in.readInt();
    phones = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (phonesExist == 1)
        in.readStringList(phones);          
    note = in.readString();
}
```

Comment: minor detail but a byte more efficient.